# Addition and subtraction not working in Update Fields in Vtiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

i know this has already been asked on some forums like in https://discussions.vtiger.com/ and I already placed a question but I haven't received any answers and do a search on related questions but I don't seem to find a definite answer to this question. I'm actually creating a dynamic field which automatically computes the difference of the two fields.

To make it more clear, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

Using EXPRESSION:

Amount For Collection - Amount Collected

and the result must be the difference of the two which is the Unpaid Amount but when I apply this and try to put data on the fields and submit my form I end up in a white screen only but when I use MULTIPLICATION and DIVISION the form proceeds and it automatically computes.

Am I doing it the wrong way, can anyone here shed some way to fix this issue. I tried this in the older version and I don't encountered these errors on Addition and Substraction.

By the way I'm using the newest version Vtiger 7.1.0

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi was actually able to solve this with a help from vtiger discussion. I only edited this file: modules\com_vtiger_workflow\expression_engine\VTExpressionEvaluater.inc